# Hibernate Unable To Locate appropriate constructor with many to one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

Hi everyone i've tried to use the following code for create a new object inside HQL query.

**Edited:**

```
"select new Family(mother, mate, offspr) from DomesticCat as mother join mother.mate as mate left join mother.kittens as offspr"
```

But i've got error :

> Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class...

When i check my constructor the property kittens is a Set, but in the error the constructor want just one element Kitten.

How can i use my query with a list in parameter ?

Thanks

Comment: Putting some more code here (and formatted) + a bigger portion of that exception would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a explicity declaration of the relations, don't need make a join.
Try this:

```
"select new Family(mother, mother.mate, mother.kittens) from DomesticCat as mother"
```

When make a question, try ever, post your declaration classes, for a deep help of the users.

Regards.